# Use Firebase uid in firestore (Vue)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore, and I want to use a user's `uid` in the query, like this:

```js
methods: {
  //...
},
firestore: {
  Cards: db.collection("Users").doc(firebase.getCurrentUser().uid).collection("Cards")
},
async beforeMount() {
  //...
}
```

This doesn't work. I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

I tried just passing the uid as a variable and fetching it in `beforeMount()`, but I get this error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uid')

What should I do?

Comment: Did you already search for this "FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions" error message, as I'm quite certain it has come up before. It means the user is trying to access data that they don't have permission to access.

Comment: Go into firebase -> firestore -> rules and check if the users have permission to view the document.

Comment: Yes, but the user *does* have the correct permissions. When I hard-code the same uid, it works.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so I think my issue is more related to order in which Vue executes things, but I can't find a way to get the uid before Firestore tries to get the collection

Comment: It sounds like firebase.getCurrentUser().uid` doesn't have a value when the code executes. If that is indeed the case, have a look into using an auth state change listener as shown in the first code snippet in the documentation on getting the current user: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, thank you for the suggestion but that didn't work either (I had the auth state change listener in `beforeMount()`). My issue was related to vuefire binding — I submitted an answer to the question below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the vuefire binding:

https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/binding-subscriptions.html#programmatic-binding

> If you need to change the bound reference while the application is running, e.g. to display a different user profile, or different product detail page, *Declarative* binding isn't enough.

I had to use *Programmatic* binding, like this:

```js
  const Cards = db.collection('Users')

...

  watch: {
    uid: {
      // call it upon creation too
      immediate: true,
      handler(uid) {
        this.$bind('Cards', Cards.doc(uid).collection("Cards"))
      },
    },
  },
```